# Trying to Removing Binary Search Tree Node in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem my remove node function.

```
void TreeNode::TreeRemove(TreeNode* &root, TreeNode* key){
TreeNode* par  = NULL;
TreeNode* curr = root;
while (curr != 0) {
    if (curr->GetData()->GetArea() == key->GetData()->GetArea()){
        if (!curr->GetLeft() && !curr->GetRight()){     //Remove leaf
            if (!par)
                root = NULL;
            else if (par->GetLeft() == curr)
                par->SetLeft(NULL);
            else
                par->SetRight(NULL);
        }
        else if (curr->GetLeft() && !curr->GetRight()) { //Remove node with only left child
            if (!par)
                root = curr->GetLeft();
            else if (par->GetLeft() == curr)
                par->SetLeft(curr->GetLeft());
            else
                par->SetRight(curr->GetLeft());
        }
        else if (!curr->GetLeft() && curr->GetRight()){  //Remove node with only right child
            if (!par)
                root = curr->GetRight();
            else if (par->GetLeft() == curr)
                par->SetLeft(curr->GetRight());
            else
                par->SetRight(curr->GetRight());
        }
        else {                                            //Remove node with two children

            TreeNode* succ = NULL;
            succ = curr->GetRight();
            while (succ->GetLeft() != 0)
                succ = succ->GetLeft();
            curr = succ;
            curr = curr->GetRight();
            TreeRemove(curr, succ);

        }
        return;
    }
    else if (curr->GetData()->GetArea() < key->GetData()->GetArea()){
        par  = curr;
        curr = curr->GetRight();
    }
    else {
        par  = curr;
        curr = curr->GetLeft();
    }
}
return;
}
```

So far, it all works except for this segment of code:

```
        else {                               //Remove node with two children

            TreeNode* succ = NULL;
            succ = curr->GetRight();
            while (succ->GetLeft() != 0)
                succ = succ->GetLeft();
            curr = succ;
            curr = curr->GetRight();
            TreeRemove(curr, succ);

        }
```

It doesn't actually produce an error. However, when attempting to actually remove a value with two children, it does not remove. I've been trying to figure this out, but cannot.

Everything else works great.

Test code:

```
20
24.98
27.4955
32.7261
34
36.6606
37.609
38
44
47.444
52.5357
55
56.285
60.9687
61.8946
62.45
63
63
65.7267
69.8387
70.4002
70.993
72
72
80.271
84.8171
85
94
96
102
103.923
107.69
110
112.818
119.059
124
129.831
139.812
142.166
149.995
156.818
164.098
168
171
174.539
179.6
180.492
182
182
194.422
194.936
199.75
202.049
205
207
237.142
238.797
250.117
267.909
269.867
279
280
285
285.657
289.972
322
328.044
336
344
350
351.286
352
356.685
370
372.29
373.006
374.7
380
382.014
405
408
420
432.804
441.333
450
471.575
480.22
484
484
484.418
490.681
495
500
520.752
542.218
551
554.931
642.912
667
672
674.74
696.75
714
714
714.926
720
728
735
748
750
774.968
868
874
894.467
900
928
950.666
980
1008
1036
1075
1150
1190
1218
1260
1292
1295
1462
1845
1974
2500
Enter an area to search for: 1974
20
24.98
27.4955
32.7261
34
36.6606
37.609
38
44
47.444
52.5357
55
56.285
60.9687
61.8946
62.45
63
63
65.7267
69.8387
70.4002
70.993
72
72
80.271
84.8171
85
94
96
102
103.923
107.69
110
112.818
119.059
124
129.831
139.812
142.166
149.995
156.818
164.098
168
171
174.539
179.6
180.492
182
182
194.422
194.936
199.75
202.049
205
207
237.142
238.797
250.117
267.909
269.867
279
280
285
285.657
289.972
322
328.044
336
344
350
351.286
352
356.685
370
372.29
373.006
374.7
380
382.014
405
408
420
432.804
441.333
450
471.575
480.22
484
484
484.418
490.681
495
500
520.752
542.218
551
554.931
642.912
667
672
674.74
696.75
714
714
714.926
720
728
735
748
750
774.968
868
874
894.467
900
928
950.666
980
1008
1036
1075
1150
1190
1218
1260
1292
1295
1462
1845
1974
2500
Found it!

Do you want to quit(y/n)?
```

The number entered should be removed from the list. It is not. Other numbers that do not have two children nodes are removed, however.

Main program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <treenode.h>
#include <shape.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string userYesNo;
    double userArea;
    int i = 0;

    vector<Rect> vRect;
    vector<Triangle> vTriangle;

    ifstream RectFile;
    ifstream TriFile;

    RectFile.open("Rsides.txt");
    TriFile.open("Tsides.txt");

    try {
        if (!RectFile.is_open())
                throw 1;
    }
    catch(int e){
        cout << "Could not open file Rsides.txt."  << endl
             << "Terminating program. Press enter" << endl
             << "to continue.";
        cin.ignore();
        return 0;
    }

    try {
        if (!TriFile.is_open())
                throw 1;
    }
    catch(int e){
        cout << "Could not open file Tsides.txt."  << endl
             << "Terminating program. Press enter" << endl
             << "to continue.";
        cin.ignore();
        return 0;
    }

    while(!RectFile.eof()) {
        Rect tempRect;

        double tempRX = -1;
        double tempRY = -1;

        RectFile >> tempRX;
        RectFile >> tempRY;

        tempRect.SetA(tempRX);
        tempRect.SetB(tempRY);

        if ((tempRect.CheckValidity(tempRX, tempRY))==true){
            vRect.push_back(tempRect);
        }
    }

    while(!TriFile.eof()) {
        Triangle tempTri;

        double tempTX = -1;
        double tempTY = -1;
        double tempTZ = -1;

        TriFile >> tempTX;
        TriFile >> tempTY;
        TriFile >> tempTZ;

        tempTri.SetA(tempTX);
        tempTri.SetB(tempTY);
        tempTri.SetC(tempTZ);

        if (((tempTri.CheckValidity(tempTX, tempTY, tempTZ))==true) && (tempTri.GetArea() != -1)){
            vTriangle.push_back(tempTri);
        }
    }

    RectFile.close();
    TriFile.close();

    TreeNode* root = NULL;
    TreeNode* newNode = root;
    TreeNode* nodeDelete = NULL;

    while(i<vRect.size()) {

        TreeNode* temp1 = new TreeNode;

        temp1->SetData(&vRect.at(i));

        root->TreeInsert(newNode, temp1);
        i++;

    }

    i = 0;

    while(i<vTriangle.size()) { //Same thing as above. However, this inserts in order.

        TreeNode* temp2 = new TreeNode;

        temp2->SetData(&vTriangle.at(i));
        //cout<<temp2->GetData()->GetArea()<<endl;

        root->TreeInsert(newNode, temp2);
        i++;

    }

    i = 0;

    root->PrintInOrder(newNode);

    while ((userYesNo != "Y") && (userYesNo != "y") && (userYesNo != "Yes") && (userYesNo != "yes")) {

        cout << "Enter an area to search for: ";
        int c = cin.peek();
        if (!isdigit(c)) {continue;}
        cin >> userArea;

        nodeDelete = newNode->TreeSearch(newNode, userArea);

        if (nodeDelete != NULL) {
            newNode->TreeRemove(newNode, nodeDelete);
            newNode->PrintInOrder(newNode);
            cout << "Found it!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            newNode->PrintInOrder(newNode);
            cout << "Not found!" << endl;
        }

        cout << endl << "Do you want to quit(y/n)?" << endl;
        cin >> userYesNo;
        cout << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the pseudo code I was working from:

```
else                                   // Remove node with two children
            // Find successor (leftmost child of right subtree)
            suc = cur->right
            while (suc->left is not 0)
               suc = suc->left
            cur = Copy suc             // Copy successor to current node
            TreeRemove(cur->right, suc->key) // Remove successor from right subtree
```

Comment: Add your test code so I can run it locally and see what you are seeing.

Comment: Added the console screen. I don't know if you want the rest of my program.

Comment: That tells me nearly nothing. Add a small `main()` function that I can run that reproduces the problem. I cannot begin to guess how you are invoking anything here.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using multiple other files with my program. But I will add in my main program.

Comment: Don't just add your main. Try to reduce you program down to isolate the problem. You might even find your problem in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
        curr = succ;
        curr = curr->GetRight();
        TreeRemove(curr, succ);
```

You are calling `TreeRemove` with a `root` of `curr` and a `key` of `succ`. However `curr` is below `succ` in the tree, so TreeRemove will never be able to find it to remove it.

I think this means you need to rethink what you are trying to achieve. It isn't entirely clear from the code. Maybe take another look at the algorithm you are using.

Comment: I think the "Copy" part in your pseudo code was meant to indicate, "Copy the value", which matches the Wikipedia  algorithm. So rather than `curr = succ` you want to call whatever function you have to copy the value of `succ` into `curr`. The next problem after that is when you call `TreeDelete` you no longer know the parent of `succ`, so your `TreeDelete` won't remove the leaf node properly. You probably need to keep a parent pointer on the way down in the previous loop - or follow your original algorithm and start the delete at `curr->right`

Comment: Yus! Thank you! That was the problem! Thank you thank you! :D